Adding total RMS noise of consecutive frequency bands
I am trying to measure total noise of a current source with a spectrum analyzer. I have measured total noise in volts (RMS) of two consecutive bands, e.g., 1kHz to 10kHz and 10kHz to 20kHz. The total noise is obtained by the ‘Band Power’ function in the spectrum analyzer. An example of the spectrum analyzer noise acquisition screen is given below.

My question is – if I want to add noise from these two bands, how should I go about it? If we assume the total noise of a certain current source in the 1kHz to 10kHz band is 15µV (RMS) and noise of the same current source in the 10kHz to 20kHz band is 25µV (RMS), then can we add the total noise from these two bands like this-√(15^2+25^2 ) µV? If not, then what is the proper way to add total noise of consecutive frequency bands?
Much obliged for your insights.

The total way to sum the noise when each contribution of independent frequency bands is given in rms values would be the square root of the sum of the squares (which is what the abbreviation rms stands for).
Some additional cautions with such measurements: if the resolution bandwidth setting for the measurement with the instrument exceeds the spacing of the frequency bands (channels), then each measurement is actually including the measurement of the other band. To be sure the channels are independent, adjust the resolution bandwidth (RBW) so that it is less than the spacing in frequency between the center of the two bands. I suggest using a RBW that is at least 10x less so that the effect between the two bands of contiguous is minimized. Using the channel power measurement on the instrument as the OP has already done is best and avoids me having to go into countless other cautions with properly measuring power on a spectrum analyzer.

Thank you for your answer. I am not sure what you mean by channels, do you mean the frequency bins?

I meant the two bands that you mentioned.

So by "spacing of the channels" you mean the span of the frequency bands or the increment along the x axis (the frequency axis)?

You have total powers (or rms quantities as the square root) for two different frequency bands that I assume are contiguous. Just make sure the spacing in frequency between the center of those two bands is greater than the resolution bandwidth setting on the spectrum analyzer for your measurement  (I suggest at least 10x better). This will ensure the power you measure within your band is not affected by the power in the adjacent band. Make sense?

And I see from your picture that your RBW is 1 Hz so you are fine— simply square each of the two rms quantities, sum them (which is a power quantity), and take the square root of that to have the total rms voltage.

Perfect. Thanks.
